# Prove subgaussian norm of a bernoulli random variables is bounded as follows:

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

Consider the centered bernoulli random variable,

$X = \begin{cases} 
      1-p & \text{with probability}~p \\
      -p & \text{with probability}~1-p \\
      \end{cases}$

Is there a direct/indirect way to prove $||X||_{\psi_{2}} = O(\sqrt p)$?

Also $||X||_{\psi_{2}} := inf \{t > 0:\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(e^{-X^2/t^2}) \leq 2\}.$

Link : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.6749.pdf gives an explicit construction.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you looking for. The link you have attached gives an explicit construction for the subgaussian norm and exactly computes the same. So a direct way to show that subgaussian norm is $O(\sqrt{p})$ is use the explicit construction in the paper.

Comment: I was looking for a way without using the exact result but from the definition itself.

Comment: In the paper $\|X\|_{\Psi_2} = Q(p)$ is described, where $Q(p)$ has asymptotics $\dfrac{0.5}{\sqrt{\ln(p)}}$ as $p\to0$, this is not $O(\sqrt p)$. Can you remark more concretely how you expect $O(\sqrt p)$?

Comment: The subgaussian parameter is "like" the standard deviation in some sense, thus $||X||_{\psi_2}$ should be roughly $c.\sqrt{p(1-p)} \leq c.\sqrt{p}$.